# X264 Decoder complete frame not come in one NAL Unit

Tags: video, h.264, libx264

I am using libX264 library for encoding purpose . After encoding data is in form of NAL Unit ()..... .This is same format( AVC) what I require  but problem is one frame come in two Nal Unit ( One frame = (length,data) +  (length,data)  ) and i need ( One frame =  (length,data)   in single nal unit).While I am converting into file then play , it show first upper part of screen and then lower . My config parameter are below

```
param.i_width = 1680//;
param.i_height = 948;
param.i_fps_num = some no;
param.i_fps_den = 1;
param.i_keyint_max = 1 ;
param.rc.i_rc_method = //;
param.rc.f_rf_constant = //;
param.rc.f_rf_constant_max = //;
param.rc.b_mb_tree = 1;
param.rc.i_vbv_max_bitrate = ; // Convert to Kbps
param.rc.i_vbv_buffer_size = param.rc.i_vbv_max_bitrate / param.i_fps_num;
param.b_repeat_headers = 0;
param.b_annexb = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you send your encoder code? Normally you should have the following code:

```
naluSize=x264_encoder_encode(h, &nal, &i_nal, pic, &pic_out);
if(naluSize_size>0)
{
    memcpy(Framebuffer, nal[0].p_payload, frame_naluSize);
    FrameBufferSize= frame_naluSize;
}
```

So you will have your encoded frame in Framebuffer and its size is in FrameBufferSize. This works like a charm in my application.

Another advice is not to touch any parameters (at least till you solve your problems) that you don't have any idea about. Just use

```
x264_param_default_preset(&param, "ultrafast", "zerolatency");
```

This will set many parameters for you. Of course, don't forget to set the resolution :)

Answer (score 0):

Need WAY more information for a complete answer, but just a guess. If the first NALU is an AUD (type 9), You can ignore it. Or do not generate them in the first place by setting b_aud = 0.